# CentOS 7 | python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0

Tags: centos, python3, django

I am deploying a django server.

I've already installed python 3.5 without errors, but for some problems when I tried to compile mod_wsgi (so I could share the `django` app in an intranet environment with apache):

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.5
```

it told me that Failed to locate the Python library /usr/local/lib/libpython3.3m.so.

Searching for the solution on Google, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777344/installing-pyslide-under-python-3-3-virtualenv-on-ubuntu-12-04-2) explaining that I needed to recompile python3 with --enable-shared flag.

so, I proceeded to remove python3 and python3.5 from `/usr/local/bin` and recompiled python3. Everything was fine, until I tried to check the python version with *python3 --version* and I got the following:

```
[rortega@Production Python-3.5.2]$ python3 --version
python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can't find any solution to this.

Comment: `ldd $(type -p python3)`  might give you some insights.

Comment: is the libpython3.5m.so.1.0 marked as not found. the problem now is the it is in the correct location, but for some reason it doesn read it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your system may not be looking in `/usr/local/lib` by default for shared libraries. When you compile things, set the environment variable:

```
export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

This is only needed when you compile things.

That or add `/usr/local/lib` to the directories searched by the system for shared libraries.

Comment: libpython3.5m.so.1.0 is indeed in /usr/local/lib. i recompiled python3 after executinr the command you gave, but i get the same error =(

Comment: i just saw [this](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/101) and you helped with that issue, what a coincidence from 1 year appart.
ill follow what it says and ill let you know the results.

Comment: GREAT!!! I been working on this issue all day, i followed this

> ../configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --with-threads
> LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make
> sudo make install

and it did the thing. Thank you so much